# Git submodules not updating?

Tags: git

I have a project in which I've included some libraries as submodules. They work fine on the machine that you add them on, but when I get home and checkout the repo, I get the folders for the submodules but they are empty.

**.gitmodules**

```
Neon@Neon-PC /cygdrive/c/xampp/htdocs/learning-lithium
$ cat .gitmodules
[submodule "libraries/lithium"]
        path = libraries/lithium
        url = git://github.com/UnionOfRAD/lithium.git
[submodule "app/webroot/css/elements"]
        path = app/webroot/css/elements
        url = https://github.com/dmitryf/elements.git
[submodule "app/libraries/li3_markdown"]
        path = app/libraries/li3_markdown
        url = https://github.com/sandelius/li3_markdown.git
[submodule "app/webroot/markitup"]
        path = app/webroot/markitup
        url = https://github.com/markitup/1.x.git
```

**Config and status commands**

```
Neon@Neon-PC /cygdrive/c/xampp/htdocs/learning-lithium
$ git submodule
-af14f48b419310935446176290e1f9dc641400e0 app/libraries/li3_markdown
-ebdcd8ca09c874f5e2ef81ec198cc441f37a4f74 app/webroot/css/elements
-328291e49a3c7e1fb76b3342f112734864836205 app/webroot/markitup
-4980010526d05c556c496ff63951da31828c5943 libraries/lithium

Neon@Neon-PC /cygdrive/c/xampp/htdocs/learning-lithium
$ git submodule update

Neon@Neon-PC /cygdrive/c/xampp/htdocs/learning-lithium
$ git submodule status
-af14f48b419310935446176290e1f9dc641400e0 app/libraries/li3_markdown
-ebdcd8ca09c874f5e2ef81ec198cc441f37a4f74 app/webroot/css/elements
-328291e49a3c7e1fb76b3342f112734864836205 app/webroot/markitup
-4980010526d05c556c496ff63951da31828c5943 libraries/lithium
```

I added these as you would normally with,
`git submodule add <repo> <path>`
`git submodule init`

The submodules are hosted on Github and my repo is hosted on Bitbucket, although I'm not sure if this is relevant.

Comment: Don't know if this will help, but have you tried cloning with the --recursive option?

Comment: @kevin628 That works! Can you form it into an answer please and I'll mark as accepted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try cloning with the --recursive option.

Comment: Although it looks like one of my submodules is broken. `Cloning into 'app/webroot/css/elements'...
      0 [main] git-remote-https 4616 child_info_fork::abort: cygldap-2-3-0.dll: Loaded to different address: parent(0x2E0000) != child(0x330000)
error: cannot fork() for fetch-pack: Resource temporarily unavailable
Clone of 'https://github.com/dmitryf/elements.git' into submodule path 'app/webroot/css/elements' failed`

Comment: Looks like my Cygwin Git is broken. Downloaded a proper Windows version and it was fine!